# VS2017 and VS2012 on same machine with 2 TFS servers?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I installed 2 VS versions and trying to connect them to different TFS server, and Looks like there is not place to do this??  my existing VS12 was working with TFS1 server, and once I launched VS17 it recognized TFS1 and I could not find a place either FILE/SOURCE CONTROL on in Team Explorer Home to add TFS2 server ?

Is there a way to have this setup ?  Under File/Source Control/Advanced/WSpaces I can delete TFS1 wspace, but this will be delete out from my PC not only from VS, right ? So I can not do this. I need to keep my old TFS1 wspace.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you handle the 2 TFS servers? According to the error message, did you check the server IDs of the two servers?

Answer (score 2):

> If the server was split into two servers, it's very important that
> **the Server ID was changed** when setting up the second server. Very weird behavior can happen otherwise.

You could find your Team Foundation Server 201x **GUID** Info in below location:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 1x.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config
```

There should be a value like

[image]

Then you could compare the GUID of two servers, change one of them and re-register db. More details about it take a look at this blog: [How to find Team Foundation Server(TFS) GUID Info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2014/04/07/how-to-find-team-foundation-servertfs-2012-guid-info/)

After this， then try to add the TFS2 server to your Visual Studio2017 again.

Comment: @Rodrigo, Tx I see only 1 server, don't see TFS2 anywhere, I concerned about this message which says TFS2 was not added b'z already exists TFS,  it doesn't make sense b'z they are diff names

Comment: @MikeS VS do not judge this with server names, they judge it with TFS server ID. Have you double check the server ID.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I finished to erase all and stay only with one TFS. Nothing worked, though I didn't try  GUID path, not avail for my enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

As personal recommendation, I would not use 2 versions of VS on the same server. This things rarely work 100% as expected. But ...

You can connect to two different tfs servers:

[image]
[image]

Then add your tfs server url.
After that, you will be connected to a different tfs server.

The last step is to setup a separate workspace folder for your new tfs server.
I recommend that you setup a fully separeted workspace for this, to avoid confusion. Something like this:

C:/src_tfs1 -> mapped to tfs1 server
C:/src_tfs2 -> mapped to tfs2 server

Comment: Grz Rodrigo, tried this and got some strange msg (put into original post). Not sure it says  tfs2 = tfs.

Comment: The message that you added is because the star-tfs2 server is already added. I reproduced the same error here when trying to add the server I already had registered. How many servers are you seeing on the list? bellow the "Add TFS Server" button?

Comment: Tx R! I updated photo, see only one original TFS server on the list.

Comment: @Patrick, I can't find this folder on my PC to edit GUID, checking more on this.

Comment: Thanks all for help, confirmed that  I messed my machine, removed both VS, install VS2017, and somehow it still remember TFS1 server, even I able to add TFS2 server.